# How do I Auto add a row and copy down values and or formulas when Query gets multiple identical responses

Tags: google-sheets

Im a concrete cutter and I have been working a job booking/managing/tracking/payroll sheet for my company.
Im very new to this and I am asking for help to finish this thing off, theres a number of issues I need Help with but mainly:
1. adding a new row on the main sheet (sheet1)  containing the same job number when more than one employee submits a form with the same job number.
eg- On sheet one see 'completed' header its compulsory in the form so i have been trying to use that column to trigger adding a row and keeping the same job# in column A.
2. Auto creating a calendar events for individual employees from row when job is booked.

I really appreciate any advice or suggestions Im struggling a little with this.

[FORM][1]
[JOB SHEET PROJECT[][2][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgyWh.png)

[1]:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PhUC9EH43adIwqEZgY01GKraucAze76_yju5huRkYuU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Im a little confused as to which sheets and which parts your having trouble with. There are multiple sheets and things going on. Can you please add a few more specifics, like a visual example of the expected final result with sample data ?

Comment: Sorry im unable to post pictures yet, i am trying to create a sheet were i link calendar, maps, forms, and sheets to basically manage the operations of my concrete cutting business. I get calls about jobs i fill in the appropriate cells in a row and send that data to calendar (by copy paste right now) to create events for my employees who do jobs all over the city with vans as their transportation then after each job is completed they fill out the linked form and from the response sheet

Comment: i populate the rest of the cells in the row that i originally put the information in when i booked the job and this allows me to see exactly what is getting done or needs to be done at any given time and also logs their working hours for payroll.there is more i can do with it also being it will become a very large data base as time goes on once we implement it.

Comment: See ac7 on sheet one and b7 on sheet 8

Comment: These are query formula locations im having issues with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your query formula on Sheet 1 in AC7 - the problem was you had an extra space before  `101` so it was looking for a string that was exactly `[space]101`  - an easy way to avoid this is also to just reference the job  number directly like this:

```
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A3:T,"select I where E="&A7,-0)
```

I can help answer the question with the other formula also but im still unclear what part is not working since I see it did poulate some information

UPDATE:

So what I did, was I added a column in the form responses sheet that uses arrayformula which will add a unique ID after a new row has been populated. The unique id is generated simply from the job # and the operator name:

```
=arrayformula(if(istext(C2:C),F2:F&C2:C,))
```

I then pull that value into the other sheet, and sort, which orders the rows in ascending order by job #:

```
=SORT('Form Responses 1'!A2:A)
```

Then using that as my `key` for the vlookup, i can then populate the rest of the rows as needed. e.g. job number:

```
=arrayformula(if(istext(A7:A),VLOOKUP(A7:A,'Form Responses 1'!A:F,6,false),))
```

Some of the values I wasnt sure which columns you wanted to pull in so I made my best guess, hopefully you can see what I did on the stackoverflow sheet I added.

Comment: It will be common for more than one employee to be working under the same job number column (A sheet 1)

Comment: So when they respond job complete for the same job number i need to auto add a row beneath pulling down the job number creating multiple rows for the same number ie 101

Comment: I just filled another form with the same job number to point  this out, you can see the completed answer went into the next row but it is in job #102 row, i need this to be a new row with #101 in column A and not affecting any other rows beneath or above if there was any, your help is really appreciated :)

Comment: @JarrodRapsonim in the sheet now looking - was messaging you on the chat but cant tell if your connected

Comment: Sorry i was just finishing a job im home on my computer now, hope i havnt missed ya

Comment: @JarrodRapson Sorry I went to bed last night had to work today - did that end up working for you ok? Let me know if you have additional questions

Comment: I cannot thank you enough ive made so much progress tonight i would like to see what you think now ive populated my main sheet are u able to go back on and use the chat?

Comment: @JarrodRapson I can jump back in a little later - im walking out the door right now heading to my office -